# Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'createDataList':.)

Tags: flutter

I tried to fetch data from the internet with moviedb API, I followed the tutorial at https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/fetch-data/

but I'm getting the below error.

> Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'createDataList':.)

This my code

```html
Future<List<DataModel>> fetchData() async{
    final response = await http.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=d81172160acd9daaf6e477f2b306e423&language=en-US");

    if(response.statusCode == 200){

      return compute(createDataList,response.body.toString());
    }
  }

  List<DataModel> createDataList(String responFroJson) {
    final parse  = json.decode(responFroJson).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    return parse.map<DataModel> ((json) => DataModel.fromtJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Screenshot of the error message
[image]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`compute` can only take a top-level function, but not instance or static methods.

Top-level functions are functions declared not inside a class 
and not inside another function

```
List<DataModel> createDataList(String responFroJson) {
...
}

class SomeClass { ... }
```

should fix it.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html

> R is the type of the value returned. The callback argument must be a top-level function, not a closure or an instance or static method of a class.

Comment: One confusion, your first line says `compute can take static methods` but docs deny it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I guess the docs were wrong and fixed in the meantime. I'm pretty sure I looked it up in the docs when I answered. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still after 1.5 years the docs are same .... i'm haveng the same problem https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When I moved it out of the class, I get another error.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ```Unhandled Exception: Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
E/flutter (18106): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
E/flutter (18106): If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.```

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew what is the purpose of your comment?

Comment: @BotondKopacz thanks for the update. This might be a change in Dart since I posted my answer.

Answer (score 7):

As per today (2020. Aug) the compute is working fine with static methods.
For me, the issue was that I was trying to return a `http.Response` object from the compute() methods.

What I did is I've created a simplified version of this class, containing what I need:

```
class SimpleHttpResponse {
  String body;
  int statusCode;
  Map<String, String> headers;
}
```

Then I've updated the original method from this:

```
static Future<http.Response> _executePostRequest(EsBridge bridge) async {
    return await http.post(Settings.bridgeUrl, body: bridge.toEncryptedMessage());
}
```

to this:

```
static Future<SimpleHttpResponse> _executePostRequest(EsBridge bridge) async {
    http.Response result = await http.post(Settings.bridgeUrl, body: bridge.toEncryptedMessage());
    if (result == null) {
      return null;
    }

    SimpleHttpResponse shr = new SimpleHttpResponse();
    shr.body = result.body;
    shr.headers = result.headers;
    shr.statusCode = result.statusCode;

    return shr;
}
```

Worked like charm after this change. Hope this helps somebody ranning into similar problem.

Comment: As of June 2021, worked like a charm. I would like to mention that documentation at [link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html) needs to be updated. It says that only primitive types can be passed between isolates. Which is not true. You can both send and receive custom types between isolates. But I only have encountered errors when passing through types that are coming from other packages. Your local types will work.