# Using compute to read large data from json file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, future, dart-isolates

I am trying to read a lot of data from a JSON file in flutter. The data retrieval results in jank so I decided to use `compute` but then it didn't return any results.

This is my code with `compute` that does not return data:

```
Future<List<City>> getCityList (BuildContext context) async{

    final response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('Assets/citylist.json');
    final decoded = await compute(json.decode, response);
    return decoded.map<City>((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

This is my code without compute that does returns data but results in jank :

```
Future<List<City>> getCityList (BuildContext context) async{

    final response = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('Assets/citylist.json');
    final decoded = json.decode(response);
    return decoded.map<City>((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

This is the code for my Futurebuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future:  getCityList(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return FlatButton(
                      onPressed: (){

                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(snapshot.data[index].name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          })
```

Comment: Does `getCityList` just not ever return? Are there any errors? Does `compute` `await` forever?

Comment: Yes, i don't understand why biy compute never turns anything here

Comment: So there as no error messages? Please address each of my previous questions.

Comment: there are no errors

Comment: Can you print `decoded` immediately after `compute`?

Comment: No, that's how I came to know that compute isn't returning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218480/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-asad-hameed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass object methods(or closures) - instead, you need to path top-level functions.

Should be `await compute(jsonDecode, response)`
Where jsonDecode is top-level function from `json.dart`.(just use `jsonDecode` func instead of `json.decode`)

Also, I suggest creating a method like decodeCities where you can decode and map your JSON.
Here u can find a sample and more details
[Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'createDataList':.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998995/invalid-arguments-illegal-argument-in-isolate-message-object-is-a-closure)

Updated:

For tests I use next JSON(12mb)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lutangar/cities.json/master/cities.json

```
final decoded = await compute(decode, response);
print(decoded.length);

List<City> decode(dynamic obj) {
  final decoded = jsonDecode(obj);
  return decoded.map<City>((json) => City.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class City {
  String country;
  String name;
  String lat;
  String lng;

  City({this.country, this.name, this.lat, this.lng});

  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['country'];
    name = json['name'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    lng = json['lng'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['lat'] = this.lat;
    data['lng'] = this.lng;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you just saying to change `json.decode` to `jsonDecode`? In my tests they can both work without issues.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore
Share your test, first one should produce an error Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message

Comment: It worked, the compute function is returning data now, but the jank is still there and it takes longer to load data now

Comment: @ASADHAMEED create a separate top-level method and do full work here(parsing and mapping)

Comment: I don't have an idea about that, can you give me an example?