# Flutter - Compute: Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '<anonymous closure>':.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to unzip a file with compute as follows.

```
class FileDownloader{

  void downloadCompleteZip(Function(double) listenerFunction){
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {
        'fileRoot': localPath,
        "filePath": completeZipLocalPath,
        "listener": listenerFunction,
        "unzipPerc": unzipPerc
      };

      await compute(unzipCompleteZipToDisk, map);
  }
}
void unzipCompleteZipToDisk(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {}
```

When i call the downloadCompleteZip function i get the following error:

> Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is
> a closure - Function '':.)

My types for variables in map are, String and Function. I think the problem is that im trying to pass a function inside map here:

```
"listener": listenerFunction,
```

My ***downloadCompleteZip*** function is longer, for the sake of example i simplified it. I really need to pass the ***listener*** key as it sends messages to update UI. How may i solve this issue of functions not being able to pass within a map inside compute?

Also, kindly please dont suggest third party lib solutions. I have seen that libs like [this can help.](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate) I am trying to keep 3rd party dependencies as low as possible.

Comment: i guess thats the only way. Seems like ill have to work for additional several hours :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function 'createDataList':.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998995/invalid-arguments-illegal-argument-in-isolate-message-object-is-a-closure)

Comment: No it doesnt, ive seen it. its unrelevant to my question.

Comment: @pskink i think its impossible to send a function with SendPort. The documentation says "The content of message can be: primitive values (null, num, bool, double, String), instances of SendPort, and lists and maps whose elements are any of these. List and maps are also allowed to be cyclic."

Comment: they/re right: you need to call `SendPort.send()` method each time  you want to update your ui with the current progress - but i forgot you can use `IsolateChannel` too - that way you work with "normal" `Stream` protocol interface: you have `stream` and `sink` properties

Comment: so with `IsolateChannel` ui uses `channel.stream.listen` and isolate uses `channel.sink.add`

Comment: i have solved my problem by passing SendPorts inside a map at initial function call, i removed function passing which was causing the error, its a bit hacky but the code is clear and no 3rd party libs, thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: yep, it is a hard, hacky way, better check `IsolateChannel` - it really pays off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution is to not pass any function nor an object that has a function as property. Then it should work.